# Ubuntu administrator prompt doesn't display

Tags: ubuntu, administrator, ubuntu-11.10

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 on a Toshiba A300-16l laptop, and have been experiencing various very strange problems recently after upgrading to the latest Ubuntu release.

The most obvious problem is that I can't install updates through "Update Manager": pressing "Install Updates" simply disables the controls for a moment, then re-enables them with no apparent effect. At this time I would have expected an administrator prompt, but nothing appears.

[image: Pressing "Install Updates" has no effect]

A similar problem is apparent when trying to install new regional settings through "Language Support": after several minutes of watching a spinning throbber, the a dialog appears informing me that the "Task cannot be monitored or controlled". Again, no administrator prompt.

[image]

Finally, where I used to be able to sleep & hibernate my machine, now I can only shutdown or reboot. Both options simply log me out to the welcome screen, and forcibly shutting down through `sudo shutdown now` hangs on the Ubuntu shutdown screen.

The problems persist after rebooting. I'm open for any ideas!

Comment: Probably better suited for the askubuntu SE community.

Comment: Just for your information, the Ubuntu dist-upgrade feature for upgrading from say 11.04 to 11.10 isnt as refined as a true rolling release distribution like Debian. Many users have found problems like these while upgrading. When i give advice to ubuntu users about upgrading I always tell them to upgrade via the new ISO and not to use ubuntu's upgrade system as it does not explain the downfalls clearly at all.

Comment: @SeanFerguson: Is there a trivial way to "restore" Ubuntu, using the latest Live CD? If so, can I retain my home directory?

Comment: how did you setup your initial installation with regards to partitioning. If you have /home on a seperate hard drive partition then it is possible. The easiest method is to simply backup your home directory to a removable media type.

Comment: I have a dual boot setup, but Ubuntu and profiles are on the same partition. Aside from `~`, what else would you recommend backing up? Secondly, is there a "restore" option on the Live CD?

Comment: @SeanFerguson: If you could post your first comment as an answer, I'd be happy to mark it as accepted. Meanwhile, I'm [running into some problems](http://superuser.com/questions/387002/mount-usb-drive-on-ubuntu-not-authorized) even getting a USB stick working.

Comment: @SeanFerguson: I used Ubuntu's backup tool to write my profile to a USB stick, then upgraded Ubuntu using the latest Live CD. All of my problems have disappeared! Thanks!

Comment: no problem Paul, its one of the annoyances of Ubuntu I find. While making the distribution easy to use they fail to warn users when beginning a distribution upgrade of the potential complications it can cause. After all Ubuntu is based of Debian Sid (unstable) and breakages do occur occasionally :P

Comment: @SeanFerguson If you could post your first comment as an answer, I'd be happy to mark it as accepted.