# Mount USB drive on Ubuntu: "Not Authorized"

Tags: ubuntu, usb-flash-drive, mount, ubuntu-11.10

I'm having [some problems with my Ubuntu 11.10 installation](https://superuser.com/questions/386617/ubuntu-administrator-prompt-doesnt-display) on a Toshiba A300-16l laptop, of which the primary problem appears to be allowing permissions escalation.

I want to backup my home directory before reinstalling Ubuntu, but I can't seem to get my USB stick mounted. Each time I plug it in, I get the following error:

> **Unable to mount USB DISK**
>   Not Authorized

[image: Unable to mount USB DISK]

The device shows up with `lsusb` as "Kingston Techonlogy Company Inc.", and `dmesg | tail` gives:

```
 sdb: sdb1
sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present
sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Attempting to mount it manually gives:

```
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/sdb
$ sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb /mnt/sdb
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

Finally, `dmesg | tail` gives:

```
FAT-fs (sdb): invalid media value (0xb9)
FAT-fs (sdb): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
```

Is there any hope of getting this working?

Comment: Is there any other machine that does recognize the USB stick, and if so, what filesystem is used on the stick?

Comment: Windows reports it as a 3.7 GB FAT32 disk and displays its contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `dmesg` information is reasonable; the media value for FAT32 should be [`0x0b`](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/partitions/partition_types-1.html).

You might want to try `/dev/sdb1`. USB mass storage is used for both harddisks and flash. Since harddisks traditionally had partitions, and flash didn't, there's no sure way to predict if a given USB device will have a partition table.

Comment: Just to add, you can use `file -s` to get some info about the device: `sudo file -s /dev/sdb` and same for `sdb1` if you have it.

Comment: Instantly worked. I should have tried the other `sdb*` devices, but for some reason was confused by the error with `sdb`.

Comment: @FatalError: Sure enough, Ubuntu lists it with "partition 1". It then makes sense that `/dev/` contains precisely `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdb1`. Thanks for the tip!